# jQ - query alternative JSON structures

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON-inline document:

```
  {
  "a": "Person",
  "alternateName": [
     {
       "alternateName": "1793 Diébolt"
     },
     {
       "alternateName": "XXX Diébolt"
     }
  ],
  "uri": "http://500051893"
  }
  {
    "a": "Person",
    "alternateName": {
       "alternateName": "A1-53167"
     },
    "uri": "http://vocab.getty.edu/ulan/500116327"
  }
```

I want to get the values from all `alternateName` keys and output it as a TSV file.

I can get the ones which have only one alternateName-object with:

```
jq -r "[ .uri, .alternateName.alternateName ] | join(\"\t\")"
```

But how can I get both: the ones with only have one alternateName-object and the ones where the first `alternateName` key has a dictionary with `alternateName` keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be working with data that has the same structure. Otherwise you're left with having to deal with weird corner cases.  `alternateName` should be an array of objects, or otherwise, replicate the root object with each of the `alternateName` objects.

Anyway, here's how you can deal with the differing types.  Use the alternative operator (`//`) along with some filtering to deal with the different cases.  You could use the `arrays` filter to handle arrays and alternate assuming objects afterwards.

```
{ uri, alternateName: .alternateName | (arrays[].alternateName // .alternateName) }
    | "\(.uri)\t\(.alternateName)"
```

Comment: the data does not come from me, so I cannot change the format but have to deal with it. Thanks for the response, I will try it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses a helper function to normalize the `.alternateName` values.

```
def vals:
  if (.|type) == "object" then .[] else . end
;      

"\(.uri)\t\(.alternateName[] | vals)"
```